# How to get the key and value type of a Map

Tags: java

I have this code that the app needs to do some check if the key of a `Map` given is `String` or not:

```
    if(instance.getClass().equals(Map.class)){
        Map map = (Map) instance;
        if(keyIsString(map)){
           // do stuff with the map
           Iterator<Map.Entry> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        }
    }
```

I can do it by getting the first item using the iterator and checking by `instanceof` however that would cause me to use two iterators. What is the best way to get the type of the Map key?

**Update:  I create a MapHelper class:**

```
public class MapHelper {
    public static String getKeyType(Map map){
        String keyKind = Object.class.getName();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Object,Object>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry = it.next();
            Object entryKey = entry.getKey();
            keyKind = entryKey.getClass().getName();
        }
        return keyKind;
    }
    public static String getValueType(Map map){
        String valueKind = Object.class.getName();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Object,Object>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry = it.next();
            Object entryVal = entry.getValue();
            valueKind = entryVal.getClass().getName();
        }
        return valueKind;
    }
}
```

Is this good enough?

Comment: At runtime, there's no guarantee that all the keys in a Map have the same type.  AFAICS, you have no choice but to "sample" one of the keys (and then assume that it's representative of all of the keys).

Comment: What's with the downvote? :-)

Comment: If you have a huge Map, your code will take a long time setting the same value again and again...

Comment: I feel there's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) scenario here, which makes this question hard to answer meaningfully.  From your comments further down, it sounds like you're trying to create a map with multiple key types.  What is the problem you're really trying to solve?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth the map is coming from a method that accepts Object parameter so the type is totally lost during code time. That is from a method: put(Object obj) --> here I need to check if the object was a map then validate it, its key type etc.

Comment: Ok, but are you saying that you're expecting a map that contains *multiple* key types, or just *one unknown* key type?  Having to dynamically check the type of every single key/value type (bearing in mind that you may need to take polymorphic types into account) seems like a lot of work.  Is the use-case here really something like: `Object obj = getUntypedObjFromSomewhere(); if (notMapOfStrings(obj)) { throw new Exception(); } Map<String,Foo> map = (Map<String,Foo>)obj;`?

Comment: I just need to know the key type and see if its a String or not (or Long if I needed)

Comment: @xybrek: But is checking just the first key sufficient?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes I think, because if the first Map key is a String then all of the other keys are String right?

Comment: Well, not necessarily, depends on how it was created.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Is there such a map that have different key types?

Comment: @xybrek: Sure: `Map rawMap = new HashMap(); rawMap.put("foo", new Bar()); rawMap.put(67, new Bar());`.  So it depends where your raw object is coming from.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ok I see, I was thinking different. This would be a Map<Object,Object> by default. So I guess there is no way around but to check all and just throw a RuntimeException when something fishy is found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot determine the type of a map at runtime. Because of **type erasure** they are no longer available.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure

> Generics are checked at compile-time for type-correctness. The generic
>   type information is then removed in a process called type erasure. For
>   example, `List<Integer>` will be converted to the non-generic type List,
>   which ordinarily contains arbitrary objects. The compile-time check
>   guarantees that the resulting code is type-correct.
>
> Consequent to type erasure, type parameters cannot be determined at
>   run-time. For example, when an ArrayList is examined at runtime, there
>   is no general way to determine whether, before type erasure, it was an
>   `ArrayList<Integer>` or an `ArrayList<Float>`.

If you cannot make sure your compiler is already checking all types correctly, your only chance is fetching an element and assume all other elements are from the same type.

Comment: I'm not sure that answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with previous comments. If the `MapHelper` class must test it on an unknown **Map** to be generic it must not set the generic map arguments.

If you use `getValueType(Map)` or `getKeyType(Map)` this will return the class (of key or value) of the last element in your map.
I don't think you are looking for it.

```
public static boolean keyIsString(Map map) {
    boolean isString = !map.isEmpty();
    String keyKind = Object.class.getName();
    Iterator<Map.Entry> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = it.next();
        Object entryKey = entry.getKey();
        if(!String.class.isInstance(entryKey)) {
            isString = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isString;
}
```

This will return `true` if all the keys in your map are String, `false` otherwise or if the map is empty.

Comment: Sure, but it's still O(N) to call `keyIsString`.

Comment: Yes but you can not verify it on generic Map (Map<>) without O(N).

Comment: I think the real problem is that the OP has an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  So we're left guessing as to what a useful solution is.  Is it to test *all* the elements?  *Any* of the elements?  To use generics?  To refactor to be type-invariant?  Something else?

Answer (score 2):

I did it in one method which returns the KEY and VALUE types names in *CSV* (Comma Separated Values) `String` like ",":

```
    public static String getMapKeyAndValueTypes(Map map) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<Map.Entry> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = it.next();
        sb.append(MapsUtils.getObjectInstanceOf(entry.getKey()))
            .append(',')
            .append(MapsUtils.getObjectInstanceOf(entry.getValue()));
        break;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Calling the method:

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("key1", 20); map1.put("key2", 30); map1.put("key3", 40);

String keyAndValueTypes = MapHelper.getMapKeyAndValueTypes(map1);
String entryKeyTypeName = keyAndValueTypes.substring(0, keyAndValueTypes.indexOf(","));
String entryValueTypeName = keyAndValueTypes.substring(keyAndValueTypes.indexOf(",") + 1);
System.out.println("Types Names: Key=" + entryKeyTypeName + " ; Value=" + entryValueTypeName);
```

And the output is:

    `Types Names: Key=String ; Value=Integer`

In one method we get both and can choose to use one or the other or both.